# Error message when creating a contact in vtiger CRM

Tags: crm, vtiger, vtigercrm, dynamic-picklist-vtiger

I try to add new contact into vtiger crm. But There is an Error message when creating a contact.
{"success":false,"error":{"code":"Record you are trying to access is not found","message":"Record you are trying to access is not found","title":null}}
.So please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Edit config.inc.php and set $log_sql variable to true. then make new contact again and check MySQL database. you can find database errors in adodb_logsql table

Answer (score 0):

First Enable comments in config.inc.php Like as below

```
ini_set('display_errors','on'); version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0') <= 0 ? error_reporting(E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED) : error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);   // DEBUGGING
ini_set('display_errors','on'); error_reporting(E_ALL); // STRICT DEVELOPMENT
```

first give file permission from below DIR :

```
\libraries\log4php\LoggerManager.php in that find 0222 then replace with 0777
\libraries\log4php.debug\appenders\LoggerAppenderFile.php in that find 0222 then replace with 0777
```

Enable log4php debugging flag in config.performance.php

```
'LOG4PHP_DEBUG' => true,
```

Instead of

```
'LOG4PHP_DEBUG' => false,
```

Open log4php.properties file and put below line

```
log4php.rootLogger=DEBUG,A1
```

Instead of

```
log4php.rootLogger=FATAL,A1
```

Then after creating a contact in vtiger CRM and check error logs in \logs\vtigercrm.log or \logs\vtigercrm.log.1 files, It should have been a field twice or you need to Do SQL MODE = ''.

Answer (score 0):

Enable log_sql in config.inc.php file, after that try to create new contact again.
Then check the adodb_logsql table for MySQL errors.

```
$dbconfig['log_sql'] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your sql_mode conform to vtiger requirements namely "sql_mode = empty"

> /usr/sbin/mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"

Result is: /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf

If neeeded, add the following configuration file:

> nano /etc/mysql/conf/mysql_vtiger.cnf

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = empty
```

Restart mysql service

> sudo service mysql restart